# Correct format specifier in C

Tags: c

I struggle with the correct format specifier in C.

I am working with a 32-bit uC and I am using `%lu` for type `uint32_t`. For `uint8_t` I am using `%u`. That works fine.

What I can't figure out is, whether I have to use `%lu` or `%u` for `uint32_t` when I am dealing with a 64-bit address with uC. And the other way around: is `%lu` the correct format specifier when I use type `uint32_t` on a 16-bit system? Or should the format specifier be `%llu` instead?

Is the format specifier dependent on the system I am working with?

Comment: [How do I print uint32_t and uint16_t variables' value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12120426/995714), [nt32_t and printf format: %d or %ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40121748/995714)

Comment: So to clarify for you: The <stdint.h> types are there exactly because the incantation needed for getting an int of the desired bit-width, is system/platform specific. Hence you need to do something "clever" to mean "32 bit" or something else on your system. This is what the answers show you how to do...

Comment: " I am dealing with a 64-bit address" --> Do not use any _integer_ print specifier.  Use a `printf("%p\n", (void*) address);`.